# code in xmlhttp.readyState==4 doen't get executed

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

```
function download() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari   
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else   {// code for IE6, IE5  
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
    } 

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
    {   //alert(xmlhttp.readyState);
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            alert (xmlhttp.responseText);
        }   
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","import.php?file="+document.getElementById('uploaded_file').value,false);
    xmlhttp.send(); 

  //  location.reload(true);
}
```

if I put alert and monitor `xmlhttp.readyState` then it shows me that its status does turn 4 and it does go in the if statement, if I don't monitor it with alert then it doesn't go in the if statement but I know import.php is working because I can see the changes in the database. I don't know whats going on...can anyone help.

Thanks

Comment: Indent your code by 4 spaces (the `{}` button), don't use `>` to mark it as a quote...

Comment: What are you putting instead of the `alert`?  Also, why do you have `reload`?  That will reload the page, possibly before the XHR call is complete.

Comment: nothing...i was putting alert just to monitor status..i have to reload page so the changes are reflected on the page but i can do with out it still the if statement doesn't get executed

Comment: How do you know it doesn't go in the `if` when the `if` is empty?  Are you using a debugger?

Comment: there is an alert in the if...i don't get any alerts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats because the `location.reload(true);` is reloading the page, and not waiting for the `xmlhttp` call to complete

UPDATE:
try setting the 3rd parameter in the `xmlhttp.open` call to `true`

from the docs:

> A Boolean indicator of whether the
>   call is asynchronous. The default is
>   True (the call returns immediately).
>   If set to True, attach an
>   onreadystatechange property callback
>   so that you can tell when the send
>   call has completed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: i removed location.reload(true);  still the same result...i am reloading the page so the records that have been changed are displayed on the page

Comment: @shazia, if you're going to reload the page, why do you even want to use XHR?  You can just use a regular (non-AJAX) GET or POST.

Comment: @shazia what is calling the `download` function? is it a submit button inside a form??

Comment: true...but i can't change the code for import.php to redirect back plus i want to figure AJAX out as well

Comment: @The Scrum Meister a buttons onclick event calls download function